# How to get connection states for a bluetooth low energy device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Follwoing is the code android uses to get the connection summary(to display the connection status labels)

```
      private int getConnectionSummary() {
      ...........................
      ...........................
      for (LocalBluetoothProfile profile : cachedDevice.getProfiles()) {
            int connectionStatus = cachedDevice.getProfileConnectionState(profile);

            switch (connectionStatus) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING:
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                    return Utils.getConnectionStateSummary(connectionStatus);

                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    profileConnected = true;
                    break;

                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    if (profile.isProfileReady()) {
                        if (profile instanceof A2dpProfile) {
                            a2dpNotConnected = true;
                        } else if (profile instanceof HeadsetProfile) {
                            headsetNotConnected = true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

As you can see from the code above, they obtain the connection status for a Classic device using the following line of code:

```
int connectionStatus = cachedDevice.getProfileConnectionState(profile);
```

The android system calls the `getConnectionSummary()` method irrespective of whether a Classic or Bluetooth Low energy device is trying to connect; but unlike a classic device, since we do not have a method by which we can get the connectionStatus for a bluetooth Low energy device, we are unable to update the connection status correctly for a Low energy device.

Full source for this class can be found [here](http://source-android.frandroid.com/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/bluetooth/BluetoothDevicePreference.java)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Bluetooth Low energy development kit you are using ?

As of now Android doesn't have native API's for  Bluetooth Low energy devices.
you may have to use third party APIs like the BLE From Broadcomm or TI or CSR.

http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/

Motorola bluetooth Low energy APIs
http://developer.motorola.com/docs/bluetooth-low-energy-api/

You can look at this page for more information on selecting a Development Kit.
[BTLE (Bluetooth Low energy) development kit - must have proximity profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370593/btle-bluetooth-low-energy-development-kit-must-have-proximity-profile?rq=1)

Comment: I already have few profiles implemented with the jar's provided by a vendor. And I understand when a profile is connected, disconnected etc. But while Android system call the method I mentioned above, I do not have a way out by which I get the connection status for a BLE device, unlike what they do for classic device in that method.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your requirement ? why you need to use this function ? can you try the 3rd party APIs